# Routing traffic between newly established S2S VPN between AWS and Azure

Tags: amazon-ec2, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

I am trying to establish a site-to-site VPN connection between AWS and Azure to connect some VMs together. I followed a [set of instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-aws-bgp) from Microsoft and have successfully connected an Azure Virtual Network Gateway to an AWS Virtual Private Gateway with BGP. Tunnels on both sides are showing as connected, and there is a small amount of traffic running across the connection.

However, I am struggling to route traffic from the VM instances to one another via their private IPs.

My AWS setup has one VPC for the S2S VPN items, which I have configured peering across to the VPC containing the EC2 instances I wish to connect to.

Essentially (based on the attached diagram) I want to route traffic between 10.3.0.4 (Azure VM) to the EC2 VMS (10.0.0.150, 10.0.0.45 and 10.0.0.23).

I am not expecting anyone to give me a magic answer (although if you can that'd be awesome!), but some pointers on where I should be focussing my efforts would be gratefully received. I'm currently assuming that it's something to do with the AWS VPC with the Virtual Private Gateway and the VPC containing the EC2 instances and correctly routing traffic between them.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

[Diagram of current setup with any sensitive info redacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Zk1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you how it works on the Azure side. What kind of VPN do you use? The Azure Native or a NVA?
Take a look at the enterprise scale framework and the landing zones.
Basically what you do linking an route table to the vnet where the VMs are also connected to.
Ideally you would have a network hub where a vnet resides in with the vpn of the gateways (and other central network resources). And then you have a landing zone which has vnet which is peered to the vnet in the network hub,the VMs are also linked to that vnet, and the vm subnet has a route table linked (UDR).